# Implement ImagePicker into React-Native Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to implement the image picker library into my react native project for android. However, I am getting a response error code of 500 which I cannot seem to understand even though I followed the video guide completely. The video guide which I followed is this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXG3AJ6OJCk.

I also linked it by running the link after I have installed the library.

Any help would be greatly appreciates.

```
npm link react-native-image-picker
```

This is the function and when I call it, it returns the 500 error as shown below

```
import { ImagePicker } from 'react-native-image-picker';

takePic() {
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker({}, (response)=> {
      console.log(response); 
    })
  }
```

Returned:

```
The development server returned response error code: 500

URL: http://192.168.1.105:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false

Body:
{"originModulePath":"C:\\New_Mobile\\FYP\\src\\components\\Drawer\\Profile.js","targetModuleName":"react-native-image-picker","message":"Unable to resolve module `react-native-image-picker` from `C:\\New_Mobile\\FYP\\src\\components\\Drawer\\Profile.js`: 
Module `react-native-image-picker` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  
1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  
3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.\n  
4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.","errors":[{"description":"Unable to resolve module `react-native-image-picker` from `C:\\New_Mobile\\FYP\\src\\components\\Drawer\\Profile.js`: 
Module `react-native-image-picker` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  
1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  
3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.\n  
4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`."}],"name":"Error","stack":"Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-image-picker` from `C:\\New_Mobile\\FYP\\src\\components\\Drawer\\Profile.js`: 
Module `react-native-image-picker` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  
1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  
3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.\n  
4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.\n    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\\New_Mobile\\FYP\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\node-haste\\DependencyGraph\\ModuleResolution.js:183:15)\n    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\\New_Mobile\\FYP\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\node-haste\\DependencyGraph\\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)\n    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\\New_Mobile\\FYP\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\node-haste\\DependencyGraph.js:283:16)\n    at Object.resolve (C:\\New_Mobile\\FYP\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\lib\\transformHelpers.js:261:42)\n    at dependencies.map.result (C:\\New_Mobile\\FYP\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\traverseDependencies.js:399:31)\n    at Array.map (<anonymous>)\n    at resolveDependencies (C:\\New_Mobile\\FYP\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\traverseDependencies.js:396:18)\n    at C:\\New_Mobile\\FYP\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\traverseDependencies.js:269:33\n    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)\n    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\\New_Mobile\\FYP\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)"}
processBundleResult
    BundleDownloader.java:10
access$200
    BundleDownloader.java:1
onChunkComplete
    BundleDownloader.java:6
emitChunk
    MultipartStreamReader.java:9
readAllParts
    MultipartStreamReader.java:21
processMultipartResponse
    BundleDownloader.java:4
access$100
    BundleDownloader.java:1
onResponse
    BundleDownloader.java:10
execute
    RealCall.java:5
run
    NamedRunnable.java:3
runWorker
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113
run
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588
run
    Thread.java:818
```

Comment: Since the error says ```Module `react-native-image-picker` does not exist``` try ```npm install --save react-native-image-picker``` & ```react-native link react-native-image-picker```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-native-image-picker does not installed ,try execute this command

> npm install --save react-native-image-picker & react-native link react-native-image-picker

you can read docs [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker)

Comment: I have installed the library prior to this. Sorry for not stating it.

Comment: use import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker'; instead of import { ImagePicker } from 'react-native-image-picker';

Comment: can i see the server response

Comment: Sorry, I did not realized that expo-image-picker and react-native-image-picker has a difference as I am using an Expo app to develop my application. Now that I have changed to expo-image-picker instead, everything is working now. Thank you for your help :)